# Showing that $|f(z)| \leq \prod \limits_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z_k}z} \right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help with this problem:

> Let $f\colon D \to D$ analytic and $f(z_1)=0, f(z_2)=0, \ldots, f(z_n)=0$ where $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n \in D= \{z:|z|<1\}$. I want to show that $$|f(z)|
>  \leq \prod_{k=1}^n \left| \frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z_k}\, z} \right|$$ for all $z \in
>  D$.

It seems that I need to use Schwarz-Pick Lemma but it seems that the problem doesn't satisfy the conditions. Another lemma that I can use is that of Lindelöf saying: Let $f:D \to D$ analytic, then $$|f(z)|\leq \frac{|f(0)|+|z|}{1+|f(0)| \cdot |z|}$$ for all $  z \in D$.

It seems to be an easy problem but I couldn't succeed in solving it.

Comment: Do you know that there is an option to thank people who help you by  accepting their answers? If not, I seriously recommend you to go through the faq.

Comment: It's possible that $f(z)$ is not a real number for some $z$, so the inequality doesn't make sense (you probably missed $|\cdot |$).

Comment: I believe you imitate the proof of the Shwartz lemma. Divide f(z) by all of the factors on the right. What does the maximum modulus principle give you?

Comment: yes, thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: Also note that the function you get when you do what I said will be analytic, because all singularities will be removable.

Comment: Does that hint help, bond? I can write up a formal answer if needed.

Comment: Yes,your hint is the base of the answer below. But I didn't understand how the fact that $f(z_k)=0$ assist the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $B(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z_k}z}.$ Note that $|B(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1.$ Define $g(z):=f(z)/B(z).$ Now, $g$ is a holomorphic map on $D$.

For $|z| < r < 1$ we have by the [maximum modulus principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumModulusPrinciple.html)
$$
\frac{|f(z)|}{|B(z)|} \le \max_{\theta} \frac{1}{|B(re^{i\theta})|} \overset{r\to 1}\longrightarrow 1
$$
Hence,

$$|f(z)| \leq |B(z)|= \prod_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z_k}z} \right|.$$

See the [Blaschke Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) as well.

Comment: I don't think you really need to assume that $f$ extends to $\overline D$ continuously for your argument to work. Couldn't just remark that (by the maximum modulus principle) for $|z|<r<1$: $$\frac{|f(z)|}{|B(z)|} \le \max_{\theta} \frac{1}{|B(re^{i\theta})|} \overset{r\to 1}\longrightarrow 1$$ so $|f(z)|\le |B(z)|$?

Comment: @Sam: That's a good point. It can be improved in this way.

Comment: It's look good but Where have you used the fact of $f(z_k)=0$?

Comment: @bond: The zeros of $B(z)$ are precisely $z_k$'s, that's why $g$ is holomorphic on $D.$

Comment: I have taken the liberty to update the answer according to @Sam's comment, so that it works without additional conditions.