# Bounding an analytic function on the closed unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have just encountered the following exercise which has me quite stumped:

> Let $ f $ be analytic on the closed unit disk, and we assume that $ | f(z) | \leq 1 $ for all $ z $'s in this set. We also have $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = f(\frac{i}{2}) = 0 $. We need to prove that $ |f(0)| \leq \frac{1}{4} $.

I thought about using Schwarz's lemma to modify the function, but in Schwarz's lemma we assume only one zero at the origin, how does one use the two zeroes here to modify the function and obtain the bound?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is a special case of [Showing that $|f(z)| \leq \prod \limits_{k=1}^n \left|\frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z_k}z} \right|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94122/showing-that-fz-leq-prod-limits-k-1n-left-fracz-z-k1-overlinez).

Comment: @MartinR : thank you but is there something simpler for our case specifically? I am interested in how one obtains this solution.

Comment: It is actually quite simple: You divide $f$ by Blaschke factors (one for each zero of $f$) and apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: I don't think I was taught that in my complex analysis course

Comment: I was taught the maximum modulus principle but the Blaschke method seems nontrivial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108622/discussion-between-martin-r-and-kroner).